# First argument passed to equalTo() cannot be an object

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try this code to get the events that their startdate equal to "Today":

```
`var ref = new Firebase("https://event-application.firebaseio.com/event");
$scope.evt=$firebaseArray(ref.child('event'));
var a= new Date(); 
ref.orderByChild("startdate").equalTo(a).on("child_added",function(snapshot){
console.log(snapshot.val() ) 
})`
```

But i get this error:

```
First argument passed to equalTo() cannot be an object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because you are using a Date object.

Check the [documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/equalto.html):

> equalTo()equalTo(value, [key])
>
> Arguments
>
> value String, Number, Null, Boolean
>
> The value to match for. The argument type depends on which orderBy*() function was used in this query. Specify a value that matches the orderBy*() type. When used in combination with orderByKey(), the value must be a string.

Comment: Could you tell me how can i change it to string

Comment: i change it to  `var a= ((new Date()).toISOString()).toString('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'); ` and it works well